# Apache POI - Erro ao abrir arquivo gerado no MS Excel

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Olá,

estou efetuando alguns testes com **Apache POI**, **versão 3.15**, para geração de relatórios **.xlsx**, utilizando o código de exemplo abaixo, apenas para gerar um arquivo:

```
package exemplousoapachepoi;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
/**
 *
 * @author lpaiva
 */
public class ExemploUsoApachePOI {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      //Cria planilha vazia
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
      //Cria arquivo com nome específico
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("pastadetrabalho.xlsx"));
      // Escreve planilha no arquivo 
      workbook.write(out);
      // Fecha arquivo
      out.close();
      System.out.println("pastadetrabalho.xlsx criado com sucesso!");
    } 
}
```

O arquivo é gerado corretamente, porém ao abrir este arquivo no MS Excel 2016 a seguinte mensagem de erro é apresentada:

[image: Erro ao abrir pastadetrabalho.xlsx]

Alguém sabe como posso estar corrigindo esse problema?

Agradeço desde já a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução parece meio boba, continuei a efetuar testes ontem com a geração de planilhas e descobri que apenas instanciar **XSSFWorkbook** não gera uma Pasta de Trabalho completa, é necessário pelo menos inserir uma planilha dentro da Pasta de Trabalho para que ela seja válida. Nesse caso com uma linha de código:

```
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Planilha 01");
```

Com isso a Pasta de Trabalho abriu sem problemas, abaixo segue um código completo da criação de uma Pasta de Trabalho com uma Planilha e a inserção de algumas informações dentro dessa Planilha:

```
package exemplousoapachepoi;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class ExemploUsoApachePOI {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      // Cria planilha vazia
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
      // Cria planilha em branco
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Planilha 01");

      // Cria objeto coluna
      XSSFRow row;

      // Construção das informações que irão preencher a planilha
      Map <String, Object[]> empinfo = new TreeMap <String, Object[]>();
      // Inserção de dados em empinfo
      empinfo.put("1", new Object[] {"ID", "NOME", "FUNÇÃO" });
      empinfo.put("2", new Object[] {"01", "Leandro", "Diretor" });
      empinfo.put("3", new Object[] {"02", "João Paulo", "Assessor" });
      empinfo.put("4", new Object[] {"03", "Daniel", "Gerente" });
      empinfo.put("5", new Object[] {"04", "Nilson", "Operador" });
      empinfo.put("6", new Object[] {"05", "Gabriel", "Assistente" });

      // Interação entre dados e escrita na planilha
      Set <String> keyid = empinfo.keySet();
      int rowid = 0;

      for(String key : keyid)
      {
          row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
          Object[] objectArr = empinfo.get(key);
          int cellid = 0;

          for(Object obj : objectArr)
          {
              XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
              cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
          }
      }

      //Cria arquivo com nome específico
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("pastadetrabalho.xlsx"));
      // Escreve planilha no arquivo 
      workbook.write(out);
      // Fecha arquivo
      out.close();
      System.out.println("pastadetrabalho.xlsx criado com sucesso!");
    } 
}
```

Encontrei um [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/index.htm) (em inglês), aborda temas como: configuração e uso da biblioteca, principais funções, exemplos de leitura e escrita em arquivos. Me ajudou bastante.

Se tiver utilizando o **Netbeans IDE**, basta baixar e descompactar a pasta da biblioteca, ir em Propriedades do Projeto, na Categoria Bibliotecas adicionar os arquivos JAR que estão na pasta da biblioteca, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei a biblioteca Apache POI uma boa solução para geração de arquivos do MS Excel utilizando Java, quem tiver interesse pode baixar no website oficial da Apache, agradeço a quem tentou ajudar ou teve interesse.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer um `out.flush()` antes de fazer o `out.close()`.